# Print in Chrome with Page-Break doesn`t work in Portrait Mode

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing, page-break

I have problems to get the page break via css working. I have something like that:

```html
<div>
  <div class="content">...</div>
 </div>
<div style="page-break-after: always; page-break-inside: avoid;"></div>

<div>
  <div class="content">...</div>
</div>
<div style="page-break-after: always; page-break-inside: avoid;"></div>
```

It perfectly works when I change the orientation while printing to landscape, but in protrait mode the gap after my page break container seems to be the size of a landscape page, its to small.

Im using Google Chrome to print this.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Just two remarks: 1) `page-break-inside: avoid;` on an empty element is a bit pointless. 2) Printing (and printing style sheets) is very neglected by browser developers and thus very unreliable. Generally it's something that you should avoid at all costs IMHO. Instead look into media that support pages such as PDF.